# Regex to extract iso code in a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

```
image_basename = 'fr-ca-test.png'

Langs = {'ca', 'fr-CA', 'en-CA'}

Langs.each do |locale_code|
  return locale_code /(\b|\_|-)#{locale_code}(\b|\_|-)/i.match(image_basename)

  end
end
```

When the filename contains fr-CA or en-CA. I would like to returns fr-CA not Ca.

How I can fix my regex?

Comment: Your `Langs` is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use a regexp in this simple example. Using `start_with?` will very likely be faster and IMHO it is easier to read and to understand:

```
image_basename = 'fr-ca-test.png'
LANGUAGES = ['fr-CA', 'en-CA', 'ca']

LANGUAGES.find { |code| image_basename.start_with?(code.downcase) }
#=> "fr-CA"
```

Comment: filename can be 'fr-ca-test.png' or test-'fr-ca.png' or 'blalb-fr-CA-bllb.png'

Comment: You might want to use `include?` instead of `start_with?` in that case. Furthermore, make sure that your `LANGUAGES` array is sorted from the most specific to less specific code because `find` returned the first match.